# Download and install SQL Server programmatically using C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, visual-studio, setup-project

I am developing software for point of sale. At the time of installation, I want to automatically download and install SQL Server if it is not installed. So I want to know how to download and install SQL Server programmatically using C#. Express edition is also fine

Comment: Express Edition? Otherwise there aren't going to be reliable, permanent, direct download links that don't require authentication, registration, or other hoops.

Comment: Express Edition is also fine

Comment: Have you tried to deploy? I think this is available as prerequisites. I know Many SW companies use Express as commercial purpose for more than 10 years. Open the property of your project and open publish section, and there you can check the availability.

Comment: Yes I tried, it's worked fine but I want to install in programmatically on particular condition

Comment: I'm not sure of the overall needs of the application, but if it only requires local access then you might be able to get away with using SQL Server Express LocalDB, in which case I believe you can distribute the MSI file and just have your installer execute it ( no need to download anything ). I know others have done that.

Comment: if you want the super simple cheat ish way...... install choclatey, use choclatey to install express

Comment: choclatey can also be installed easily via powershell script